# Access-Control-Allow-Origin fetch js

Tags: javascript, fetch, cors

estaba probando a realizar una sencilla llamada a la API de un juego para pintar un par de datos con el metodo FETCH
pero al hacerlo la consola me devuelve este error (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Javascript -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>




  <body>
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <div class="container my-5 text-center">
     <button class="btn btn-danger w-100" onclick="traer()">Obtener</button>
     <div class="mt-5" id="contenido">


     </div>
   </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var contenido = document.querySelector('#contenido')


function traer() {
   fetch('https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/jugador?api_key=13412341324123413')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => {
     console.log(data.id)
     contenido.innerHTML = 
     `<p>Nombre: ${data.name} </p>` 
   })



}
```

Se que es tema de los headers de cors pero no se donde tocarlo o donde ponerlo, si en el codigo o en algun archivo config etc
no estoy usando un servidor local si no directamente el navegador firefox

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, el encabezado CORS debe configurarse en el Servidor. No hay nada que puedas hacer desde el lado cliente si te arroja ese error. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para alguien que como en mi caso tenga el error Access-Control-Allow-Origin y no este usando un servidor en local puedes en tu navegador instalar una extension 
llamada Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin tanto para firefox como para google chrome .